# underlining text in sifr

Tags: text, sifr, replace, underline

I've recently been getting into using sifr as a healthy alternative to generating text as image using php. I've got a question about underlining text, for a website design I need to be able to specify the thickness of the underline and the distance from the text, is there any way to accomplish this with sifr? If not, is there a way to be able to solve this with css? I've been trying to get my head around it, but since I haven't found a way to get the exact width of the sifr text, I'm doubting whether it's possible at all.

Any thoughts on this? They're much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Thijs.

Comment: a note, maybe of importance: I'm able to change the underline thickness and offset in the metrics of the font itself, but it seems that these values aren't used by sifr / flash, is this true?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Flash renders a fake underline, and no, you can't change how it looks. The only option would be to render a border underneath the Flash movie using HTML & CSS, but I don't that'll work very well.

With sIFR 3, if you specify the `fitExactly: true` option in the replacement, the Flash movie will be the same width as the internal text.

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thanks for the quick response. As for the html/css underline, this can only work if the flash movie has the same size as it's textual content, is there a way to achieve this? Or another option maybe, is there a way to obtain the absolute width of the text in the movie?